# How to do a Vote Up for a Comment

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a like button (Not Facebook), just an Up Vote functionality in the comments of my article for my website. I've placed each like button inside the while loop that echo out the comments so that each like button image appears in each comments box, with this part of my code

```
           if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { 
 echo"<a href=\"\"><input type=\"image\"name=\"like\"src=\"like.jpeg\"></a>";
    }
```

And i'm trying to check if the button is clicked, with this code, if yes, it should insert the specified values into the likes table.

```
         if(isset($_POST['like'])) {

   $query1   = "INSERT INTO likes (
                likes_id, user_id, 
                comment_id, total_likes)  
                VALUES (NULL,'".$_SESSION['logged_username']."', '".$_SESSION['article_id']."', $page_name+1)";
                mysql_query($query1) or die mysql_error());
```

but the code is not working at all.

No error is showing and nothing is inserted into the likes table.

Please how can I make this work/where is the problem coming from? What might be a better solution if this is not do-able?

Please forgive my code formatting, i meant no disrespect to this community.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the upvote button cause the form to be submitted, or does the user hit a submit button elsewhere on the page? If not, PHP doesn't know that the upvote button was clicked, and won't take any action in response. If you want to do the database query as soon as the button is clicked, without reloading the page, you'll need some AJAX/jquery.

Comment: die shouldn't be capitalized and mysql_error() shouldn't have spaces between "_" (underscore) and "error".

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis after `die`. Maybe your copy/paste button is broken.

Comment: @nadirs The button that submits the comment is different from the button that submits the up vote.

Can you please turn to a good straight to the point  AJAX/jQuery tutorial on this issue.

I have editted my question with the weird spaces.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure out what the actual error is, do this.

```
mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You do have a web form that's posting to your php file, with a hidden input called 'like', right...?

Comment: No i dont. The only other button on the form is the button tnat submits the comments made by the user...

Comment: Then I don't believe your code will ever execute.  if(isset($_POST['like'])) {, that if statement needs to succeed, and if there's no post data with the key "like", then your mysql query will never get executed.

Comment: pls what do you suggest i do? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have a parenthesis where there shouldn't be one:

```
mysql_query($query1));
                    ^
```

Comment: Thank for pointing this out. But after removing it and adding or DIE mysql_error()) it didnt still show any error...

Comment: @user1378680: If you type `<?php if return foreach foobar ?>` do you get any error? You should get something like this: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN, expecting '('`. If not, maybe your PHP isn't set up correctly.

Comment: "An error occured" Can you be more specific? Was it the expected error or another error? If it was another error, what was the error message?

Comment: @user1378680: Then it's surprising that major syntax errors like mismatched parentheses aren't being caught. Perhaps the code you are trying to run is a) inside a comment block or b) inside a string literal c) not saved to disk d) saved to disk but not in the right place e) not being run f) any number of other possibilities. If I were you I'd spend some time getting the error message showing properly first before trying to fix the cause of the error.

Comment: Thanks..... Syntax errors fixed, but nothing showing on screen and no row inserted into db.

Comment: @user1378680: "Syntax errors fixed". Wait... that's the **exact** opposite of what I said you should do. If I were you I'd spend some time *getting the error message showing properly* first **before** trying to fix the cause of the error. Trying to fix code without being able to see the error messages is like cooking without tasting it - you've no idea whether adding more salt makes it better or worse.